# How can I create a space line (like a br) when user clicks on button?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I need a javascript function or really anything so when the user put names in the input type text, it puts the text on a paragraph below #final and so on continuosly adding a space whenever the user clicks the button.

```js
function ir() {
  let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  let monto = document.getElementById("monto").value;
  let total = document.getElementById("total");
  let final = document.getElementById("final");
  let aporte = document.getElementById("aporte");

  for (i = 0; i < monto; i++) {
    total.innerText = ` ${nombre} : ${monto}`;
  };

  if (total > 0) {
    monto + monto
  }

  final.innerHTML = `${monto}`;
  aporte.innerHTML = `${monto}`;
};
```

```html
<html>


<p>Nombre</p>
<input type="text" id="nombre">
<br>
<p>Monto</p>
<input type="number" id="monto">
<br>
<button onclick="ir()">Enviar</button>
<br>
<p>Total: <span id="final"></span> </p>
<div id="total">
</div>
<p>A cada uno le toca aportar: <span id="aporte"></span></p>
</div>

</html>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by a text line? Your question is a little bit unclear

Comment: sorry, I edited it so it can be a little more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function ir() {
  // Set everything to const because they don't change and it's good practise
  const nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;

  // Monto changes below, so we can use LET!!
  let monto = document.getElementById("monto").value;

  const total = document.getElementById("total");
  const final = document.getElementById("final");
  const aporte = document.getElementById("aporte");

  // Create new element under total
  const lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
  let newTotal = document.createTextNode(` ${nombre} : ${monto} `);
  total.appendChild(lineBreak);
  total.appendChild(newTotal);


  // Set monto to monto + the value already there
  // Use Number to make it number (without Number it's string, 1+2 = 12 and not 3)
  monto = Number(monto) + Number(final.innerHTML);

  final.innerHTML = `${monto}`;
  aporte.innerHTML = `${monto}`;
};
```

What it does is it creates a new element beneath total and updates it each time the user clicks the button.

The total is also updated too.

Comment: Correction it appends the chil to total and not beneath it

Comment: @innocent, sorry, i meant quite literally **below** it, when reading the code, it appears below it... Besides, it's self explanatory, it's a child, so we can assume that it is inside of it's parent

Answer (score 0):

One potential way to do this would be to check the values of `nombre` and `monto`. If they are empty (or just spaces), we can create and append a <br> element.

```js
if (monto.trim() == "" || nombre.trim() == "") {
  let lineBreak = document.createElement("BR");
  total.appendChild(lineBreak);
```

I'm not exactly sure which element you wanted to append this to, so change it accordingly to `element.appendChild(createdElementName)`.